# Origin of short-lived threads in an application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, profiling

I am currently health checking an application which experiences UI stuttering during heavy usage.

Using [Microsoft Concurrency Visualizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627193.aspx) extension for Visual Studio 2015, showed that quite a lot of short-lived threads are created and stopped after ~100ms of execution.
Unfortunately, their displayed callstack is like *clr.dll!0x98071* *ntdll.dll!0x634fb* and I am not quite sure how to extract useful information out of it.

I have no clue what is the purpose of those threads and which part of the code in the application is creating them.

**How can I better identify where each one of them gets started?**

In the code, I was able to grep a handful of Tasks, another of QueueUserWorkItems, several dozens of plain Thread instantiations, some System.Threading.Timer & System.Timers.Timer, no Reactive Extensions. I put breakpoints for all of them but it seems I am missing some...

I don't think those are from the threadpool because they would be displayed in synchronisation state in concurrency visualizer, instead they just end, and another one with another Id gets created later. But maybe I am misleading.

We also use a few third-party libs and a bunch of JuggerNET generated code, so maybe the origin is not even in the application itself.

Comment: This is a bit of a blind guess, but maybe they're GC threads?

Comment: Thank you for your input. Though, isn't GC supposed to run of the thread that triggered it and not spawn any new thread, according to [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)? (I don't have <gcServer> enabled btw)

Comment: Please put voting commentary in the comments rather than in posts - most readers do not sign in or vote, so it is not of interest to most readers. I personally don't think appeals not to downvote work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find the culprit of those short-lived threads by looking closely at some of the cryptic callstacks, which included for instance:

```
mmdevapi.dll
wdmaud.drv
avrt.dll
audioses.dll
```

It led me to thinking that I should double check the sound alert system. It was indeed this one which spawned those threads.

**Note:**

I will not accept my answer however because I would like someone to share a better process or any kind of tips and tricks for diagnosing unwanted threads origin.